# Could the US ban all but one specific weapon?

Tags: united-states, second-amendment

Recent rulings determined Americans have the right to bear arms for protection. Since several weapons are already illegal to own, could that be extended so as to ban any gun that didn't conform to very exacting specifications? For example legal guns could only have a barrel length of 5", a magazine capacity of 5 rounds, a bullet size of 10mm, etc.

Comment: There are plenty of court rulings that overturn bans on certain types of weapons

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that hunters may have shotguns and rifles of different types. As I recall, there has been no attempt to prevent weapons commonly used for hunting unless those weapons are of a design considered to be *assault weapons*. Perhaps some clarification should be made to the question, since you appear to be referring only to *personal protection* using a pistol, while saying *any gun*.

Answer (score 5):

**Depends on what the Supreme Court says.**

There are different schools of thought how the Constitution should be interpreted. One is to try and understand the **intent** of the writers. This is understood by looking at the words, but also at other documents of the era to resolve ambiguities. Another is to try and understand the **original meaning** of the words at the time, distinct from the specific speaker. Yet another is to apply **modern understanding** of the language. The right to bear arms might be understood to mean

- the right to bear a current set of infantry weapons, that is a (fully automatic) assault rifle, optionally a grenade launcher, grenades, and anti-tank rockets,
- the right to bear an 18th century **stand of arms,** that is a flintlock rifle, a bayonet, and a cartridge case, or perhaps a sword and flintlock pistol, or
- something in between.

Comment: Or something outside of them: the right to bear nuclear missiles, or pointed sticks?

Answer (score 1):

This question, as asked, is off topic (it's a legal question, not a political one) but since it's answerable, I'll answer it in a legal context.

The US congress can make a law that restricts weapons to a certain type (such as 1 manufacturer, one model, one size). This law will likely get struck down by the US Supreme Court however, due to a legal concept called the [undue burden standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undue_burden_standard?wprov=sfla1). This is not fringe legal theory. This is a standard that is famous due to the equally famous most litigated law in US history (the 14th amendment).

> In short, the undue burden standard states that a legislature cannot make a particular law that is too burdensome or restrictive of one's fundamental rights.

Examples where this is used

> One use of the standard was in Morgan v. Virginia, 328 U.S. 373 (1946). In a 7-to-1 ruling, Associate Justice Stanley Forman Reed fashioned an "undue burden" test to decide the constitutionality of a Virginia law requiring separate but equal racial segregation in public transportation. "

Another,

> The standard was applied by Associate Justice Sandra Day O'Connor in her dissent in City of Akron v. Akron Center for Reproductive Health, 462 US 416 (1983). O'Connor utilized the test as an alternative to the strict scrutiny test applied in Roe v. Wade, 410 U.S. 113 (1973).

So requiring that everyone has to use this private buyer that manufacturers in one state that sets the price to a specific level (and likely can't meet the demand of the US) will fail, likely in several ways. The guns have to be at an affordable price, available for all who want, and can't form a legal monopoly. If access is restricted (due to e.g. no one can make or sell the gun at an affordable price) then this will run afoul of the undue burden test. You'd have to wait for the situation to occur to prove that it would happen, but Court rulings tend to preempt situations that would be problematic so if need only occur in theory.